# How to create an AMI from a running/existing windows instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008

I have a running/existing EC2 instance with Windows Server 2008 with instance backed, how do i create an AMI from this existing instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under "EC2 Service Settings" on the existing instance, select if you want to run sysprep after the bundled instance is re-instantiated.

Then, go to the AWS management console, right-click your instance, and click "Bundle". Select your credentials and destination S3 bucket.