# AWS auto scaling : could not create exact replica of instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I created a t2.micro EC2 instance and configured node.js on it. That is running fine.

Next I tried to create an Auto Scaling group with this instance that creates a Launch Configuration then Auto Scaling group with Launch Configuaration also created successfully.

The problem is that when Auto Scaling works, the new instance created is not the exact replica (image) of the old instance. It does not copy my node.js configuaration and the data files.

Where I am going wrong and how achieve this requirement on AWS?

Comment: I think you want to use [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)? For installation check [Node.js on Amazon Ec2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html?tag=ad-backfill-amzn-no-20). Also, [Creating AMI from running EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641922/how-to-create-an-ami-from-a-running-existing-windows-instance)

Answer (score 4):

When Auto Scaling launches a new Amazon EC2 instance, it uses the Amazon Machine Image (AMI) specified in the Launch Configuration. The new instance will have the exact same contents as the AMI.

It sounds like you are either using a standard Amazon-issued AMI, or you created your own AMI **before** you configured your instance. Any configurations done after the AMI creation will not carry across to new instances because it is not part of the AMI.

You should:

- Launch an instance and configure it how you wish
- Create an AMI (Actions / Image / Create Image)
- Create a Launch Configuration that uses that AMI
- Edit your Auto Scaling group to use that Launch Configuration

Any new instances launched by Auto Scaling will use the new AMI, which will have all your configurations.

An alternate to create a custom AMI is to use a [User Data Script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) that will automatically run when a new instance starts. This script can download software, change settings and generally personalize the instance. This could be easier to update rather than having to create new AMIs when you want to change something. The User Data script can be entered into the Launch Configuration, which will be used by Auto Scaling when launching new instances.